# How to sync Datagridview and datasource when user sorts column?

Tags: asp.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridview in a windows form project that is directly bound to a Dataset through a SqlDataAdapter. I have one editable column which a user can edit and that works great if the user does not sort the column.

If the user sorts the column the underlying datasource gets out of sync with what the Datagridview is displaying.

What is a standard technique to keep the gridview and datasource in sync when a user sorts it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding auto sorting does not works with DataGridView, for performing sorting you need to sort the datasource and then rebind it to the GridView as shown in code below

```
private void Sort_DataGrid(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Never use Queries like this always use Stored procedures
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Categories", myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(ds, "Categories");
    DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Categories"]);
    if ((numberDiv % 2) == 0)
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
    else
        dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
    numberDiv++;
    myDataGrid.DataSource = dv;
    myDataGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: How would you call the Sort_DataGrid event? Also where is the numverDic been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find an event that triggers for clicking on the header to sort a datagridview.